# Vertical align center text along with the progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to reduce the height of bootstrap's progress bar but the issue is how can I make it in the center vertically same line as the text beside it. You can see the below sample with a reduced height progress bar that has a margin like or empty space below it.

```css
.progress-num {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.progress {
    height: 0.5em !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="progress-num">8/10</span>
        <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting using `margin-top`

```css
.progress-num {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.progress {
    height: 0.5em !important;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="progress-num">8/10</span>
        <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just wrap the text and the bar in a containing element:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="progress-stuff">
        <span class="progress-num">8/10</span>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS (no need for magic numbers for margins):

```
.progress-stuff {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* ensure all elements vertically aligned */
}

.progress-num {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.progress {
  flex: 1; /* ensure bar fills remaining horizontal space */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed the text within the progress bar, in case you do not insist on having a height of `0.5em`. Just remove the class `sr-only` from your inner `span` element and move the text `8/10` to that element. There is no need for adjusting the text then, because it will always be within the progress bar.

You can even omit the inner `span` completely, if you do not want to apply any additional styling. I kept it in my code snippet, because it keeps the code more structured:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
            <span>8/10</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**In ANY case**, even if you keep your label outside of the progress bar, fill the `<span class="sr-only"></span>` with content, e.g. `<span class="sr-only">8/10</span>`. The `sr-only` stands for *screenreader-only*, i.e. visitors with  visual impairments rely on the text within that element!

Even though *you* cannot see it on screen, other people *need* that information in order to tell, how far the action progressed.